# компилируется нормально, но не видит ошибок, просто дотнет завершается и пишет проблему stack overflow. Че делать?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

https://hatebin.com/kkwvdvtzjn
помогите плес, вот такая вот беда

Comment: Вы издеваетесь? Вам уже дали ответ, объяснили почему и как, закрыли вопрос дубликатом. Вы решили создать еще один вопрос, сделав еще его и вовсе без описания?

Comment: Я попытался исправить. И что за дубликат?

Comment: И плюс у меня все поля публичные

Comment: Что вы пробовали то? Ваш вопрос закрыли, там есть ссылка на ответ. Он вам непонятен? Хорошо, попробую объяснить. У вас `public bool isBroken` возвращает в `get` сама себя (`return isBroken;`), в итоге у вас получается нечто на подобие `получить isBroken` -> `получить isBroken` -> `получить isBroken` -> `получить isBroken` и так до бесконечности. Вам нужна отдельная переменная (поле), которое будет содержать значение этого свойства и на которое она будет ссылаться, либо уберите все внутри и оставьте `public bool isBroken {get; set;}` (ибо у вас нет логики там). Об этом всем написано в дубликате

Comment: А,все понял.масленок еще,мне говорили чтото про рекурсию,но не учил еще,разбираюсь с ней уже

Comment: Господи, какой кошмар.... правда, извините, наболело....